# Getting the name of a variable instead of its value

Tags: variable

I want to get the name of a variable instead of its value in output. Say I have a function in which I have vectors
`e={1,0,0,1}` and `f={1,1,0,1}`, and the input for the function is a symbol (e or f). Now, in output, I want to make a grid which shows the symbol entered in input in one row, and its value in the second row. How would I do that? I tried the function `HoldForm`, but that did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
e = {1, 0, 0, 1};
SymbolName[Unevaluated[e]]
```

Result:

```
e
```

Another option, if to be used inside a function (as noted in your comment), would be to design the function to accept the symbol name instead of the symbol (or require both to make things clearer). Here is a version with just the symbol name. The symbol is extracted in the function.

```
x = 5;
Plus5[symbolname_] := 
 (s = Symbol[symbolname];
     s = s + 5;
   Return[{symbolname, s}])

Plus5["x"]
```

This returns:

```
{x, 10}
```

Comment: It does not work if I enter it through a function. The function has an input, let's call it `sign_`, then I have the e vector inside of the function. So my goal is to input `function[e]`, and get e in the output later.

Comment: The `Symbol` function was what finally solved this problem, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

`HoldForm[]` is surely an important ingredient. The other important bit is that whatever function you write should have an attribute like `HoldFirst` or `HoldAll` to prevent premature evaluation. As a simple example:

```
SetAttributes[gg, HoldFirst];
gg[x_Symbol] := Column[{Row[{HoldForm[x], "="}], x}]
```

Then,

```
ff = {1, 1, 0, 1};

gg[ff]
   ff=
   {1, 1, 0, 1}
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't seem to work, which is probably my fault. If we just forget the grid or any formatting, just a way to get a variables name instead of its value, perhaps as 
a string. How would I do that?

Comment: "it doesn't seem to work" - Can you try this on a fresh kernel, then?